# Setting Added Email Subscription Status To "Unsubscribed"

Tags: c#, post, mailchimp, patch, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm looking at setting the status of an added email entry from my enquiry form to unsubscribed. Currently it defaults to subscribe to the general mailing list. From what I gather I could let it add an entry and then use a PATCH request, but that's bad practice.

[Here](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/) is the documentation I'm working off. My intention is to add them to this General mailing list as an unsubscribed member so their details are stored.

```
    private string InsertIntoMailChimpGeneralList(string firstName, string lastName, string email, string mailChimpListIDGeneral)
{
    string returnable = "";

    var apiKey = WebConfiguration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpAPIKeyGeneral"];
    var listId = WebConfiguration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailChimpListIDGeneral"];
    var subscribeRequest = new
    {
        apikey = apiKey,
        id = listId,
        status = "subscribed", //This does nothing no matter where put
        email = new
        {
            email = email
        },
        double_optin = WebConfiguration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailChimpDoubleOptInGeneral"],
    };
    var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscribeRequest);

    //Examine response and process
    var responseString = CallMailChimpAPIGeneral("lists/subscribe.json", requestJson);
    dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

    return returnable;
}
```